# Error about padding occurs during my attempt to decrypt string data from a FileStream using Rijndael

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt some strings (actually a walkaround for encrypt an `XElement` object) into a file using `Rijndael`. However when decrypting, a `CryptographicException` will be thrown with the message "**Padding is invalid and cannot be removed**".
I've been searching several posts for possible solutions, in which someone mentions the `PaddingMode`, the `FlushFinalBlock()` method, and others.
Also someone has mentioned that it's because reading directly from a `FileStream` will set the length of the stream to that of the file, thus leaving no room for padding, but I don't know how to resolve the issue. Please kindly give your suggestions.

```
        var root = new XElement("Users",
                            new XElement("User", new XAttribute("id", "1"), "User1"),
                            new XElement("User", new XAttribute("id", "2"), "User2"));
        var r = Rijndael.Create();
        r.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        using (var fs = File.Open(@"D:\user.xml", FileMode.Create))
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fs, r.CreateEncryptor(r.Key, r.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(cs, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            sw.Write(root.ToString());
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        }

        var r = Rijndael.Create();
        r.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        using(var fs = File.Open(@"D:\user.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        using(var cs = new CryptoStream(fs, r.CreateDecryptor(r.Key, r.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(cs, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            var root = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: Try without `FlushFinalBlock()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to [flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) the stream writer as well.
As a note, make sure you actually use a random IV ( which you are doing here). Sometimes people write code like this and then when the go to use it to decrypt the file later, the realize they don't have the IV and so they just hard code it.  Just prepend it to the file.

```
  {
        sw.Write(root.ToString());
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        sw.flush();
    }
```